# VSCode not showing me some suggestions (ex: not suggesting Console.WriteLine, not suggesting Console.ReadLine)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, autosuggest

On VSCode, suggestions used to show up like for "Console.ReadLine" or "Console.WriteLine" but now it doesn't show up anymore. I'm not sure if it's related but I recently uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 & Visual Studio since I decided to just use VS Code from now on.

I tried reinstalling .NET Core SDK, then I reinstalled VS 2019. At first I wasn't getting suggestions in VS 2019 too after I reinstalled it. But after I installed ".NET Compiler Platform SDK" it started showing up again, but not on VS Code.

[image: Me writing Console.w , expecting to get "WriteLine" as a suggestion but only "while" pops up]

(Note: I'm a complete newbie)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308647/autocomplete-not-working-well-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, I haven't done anything yet but it's suddenly back to normal now. Thanks everyone though! (Also yes I had already installed the C# extension(?) from the marketplace, so I don't really know what the issue was here)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is called **intellisense** aka Intelligent code completion.
You need to install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) from Visual Studio Marketplace.
There is also manual how to use it.