# vscode auto complete not working fine and complete

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, xampp

I have **xampp** and **vscode** installed on windows 10. I have installed the most recommended **extensions** for **php autocomplete** but it just does not work for me. for example it does not autocomplete this:

```
$conn = new PDO();
$conn->prepare();
```

I added the path variable and done lots of searching but I could not find a solution.

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308647/autocomplete-not-working-well-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: You can try out the [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) extension, which is available for download in the Marketplace. It's a great extension if you want PHP auto-complete.

Comment: @Al-Amin my problem is a step before snippets. after i install some extensions and i use `ctrl+space` the list of recommendations does not change, it just show the result like i have not installed them. i think i have problem with the set up of extensions like intellisense.

Comment: It is very tough to say what is really problem in your vscode , but i would recommend you to update the vscode to latest version and install the plugins again. If it does not solve the issue then search in github vscode for same problems or create an issue there if don't find any solution there