# Windows 11 (using vscode) javascript autocomplete don't work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, windows-11

Good evening, I come to you because recently my autocomplete on vscode (especially in javascript) does not work anymore, I have another PC with the same version of it so I made a copy of the files on my other PC but still nothing. I also tried to completely reinstall vscode but still nothing
Any idea ?

Comment: PFFT autocomplete is a crutch anyway. lol jk. This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308647/autocomplete-not-working-well-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi！here is my suggestion.
You can enter the management in the lower left corner, select settings, and then search for "snippets" to see if the relevant options are turned off.
If those are opened normally, it may be that the relevant extension is missing, then you can click the extension on the left, and then search for the relevant language extensions.